# Force app to read from layout-ar

Tags: android, layout

I am asking if There is a way to force the android application to read from Arabic layout folders and Arabic values folder whatever the device language ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You have to force a custom locale.

Comment: Could you please explain more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force a different locale like this:

```
protected static void setLocale(final Context ctx, final String lang)
{
    final Locale loc = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(loc);
    final Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.locale = loc;
    ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(cfg, null);
}
```

In your case, use it so

```
setLocale(getApplicationContext(), "ar")
```

This will take the values from your "ar" folders (drawables-ar, values-ar, layout-ar, ...)

Comment: it works great !
but how to refresh the current activity to be loaded from layout-ar ?!

Comment: Finish and reload your activity (to see it in action before coding, just rotate your device or emulator)

Comment: there is a problem action bar title isn't affected by changing to custom locale ?

Comment: This is strange. It should read the string from values-ar. If you set the title to be read from a string. Anyway, you can force the title to a string by code. Something like: `strTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.app_title);`

Comment: yea I use it 
I determine it in activity tag in manifest file by this attribute android:label="@string/Activity_title"

Comment: No... if you only set it in the manifest, it will never be updated. set it in code, in the onCreate method. So, at every start, it will get the string from the proper localized folder.